# ¿Como recibir un valor mayor durante 10 min?

Tags: java

Disculpen, como puedo asegurarme de recibir un valor "x" mayor durante "y" tiempo

```
Parameter pHhrMinutesAlarm = parameterService.findByShortDescription("hrMinutesAlarm");
        spresult.setpHrMinutesAlarm(pHhrMinutesAlarm.getValue());
        Parameter pHrAlarm = parameterService.findByShortDescription("hrAlarm");
        spresult.setpHrAlarm(pHrAlarm.getValue());

        List<DataCollection> previousHrDataNMinute = dataCollectionRepository.getPreviousDataNMinute(sd.getId(), pHhrMinutesAlarm.getValue(), last.getDateDevice());
        spresult.setHeartRate(last.getHeartRate());
        var heartRateAVG = 0.0;
        for (DataCollection dataCollection : previousHrDataNMinute) {
            heartRateAVG= heartRateAVG + dataCollection.getHeartRate();
        }
        heartRateAVG = heartRateAVG /previousHrDataNMinute.size();
        if (heartRateAVG >= pHrAlarm.getValue()){
            spresult.setHrAlert(1);
            spresult.setHrMsgSent(pHrAlarm.getDescription());
            Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
            alarm.setAlarmDate(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(strDateNow));
            alarm.setType(2);
            alarm.setDeviceID(sd.getDeviceID());
            alarm.setDescription(pHrAlarm.getDescription());
            alarm.setId_request(String.valueOf(last.getId()));
            alarmService.save( alarm);

        }
        spresult.setSpHrResult(heartRateAVG);
```

ya que en el codigo anterior solo valida cuando el promedio (heartRateAVG)fue mayor a pHhrMinutesAlarm.getValue()(donde se extraen los minutos) donde el arrylist me trae de la bd

```
@Query(value = "SELECT td.* from tblsp_datacollection td where datedevice >= ( ?3 - interval ?2 minute ) AND ID_device = ?1 AND datedevice <= ?3", nativeQuery = true)
abstract List<DataCollection> getPreviousDataNMinute(Long idDevice, Double minutes, String date);
```

cabe decir que no me sirve ya que lo que necesito es recibir el valor mayor a pHrAlarm.getValue() durante 10 minutos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin conocer en detalle tu librería, en Java 8 se puede hacer lo siguiente:

En lugar de:

```
        for (DataCollection dataCollection : previousHrDataNMinute) {
            heartRateAVG= heartRateAVG + dataCollection.getHeartRate();
        }
        heartRateAVG = heartRateAVG /previousHrDataNMinute.size();
        if (heartRateAVG >= pHrAlarm.getValue()){
        ...
```

utilizar:

```
        if (previousHrDataNMinute.stream().allMatch(e->e.getHeartRate() >= pHrAlarm.getValue())) {
        ...
```

Otra opción más tradicional es chequear en el for:

```
        boolean checkAlarm = true;
        for (DataCollection dataCollection : previousHrDataNMinute) {
             heartRateAVG = heartRateAVG + dataCollection.getHeartRate();
             if(heartRateAVG < pHrAlarm.getValue()) {
                  checkAlarm = false;
                  break;
             }
        }
        if (checkAlarm){
        ...
```

Comment: Tienes mucha razón. Aplique la segunda opción, quite el contador y la división de heartRateAVG y utilice directamente el dataCollection.getHeartRate() y con esto ya me valido que en todo mi arrayList de un select menor a x minutos estuviera por encima del valor que esperaba.

Comment: Solo que si dejo de recibir datos y despues de sierto tiempo recibo datos y estan por encima del valor, directamente se ejecuta  el if(checkAlarm) sin aver pasado los minutos esperados por que mi ArrayList sigue cumpliendo pero los minutos aun no